# Containers don't have ports

Tags: linux, docker, centos, containers, ports

I have some weird issue. All of my 8 containers are running and they are up, but non of them are showing ports (they are blank) on `docker ps -a`.

The weirdest thing is that all of those containers have been running normally last night showing ports on all of them. Also, I can enter each of those containers without any problems using `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`.

I have restarted my server and ports are still not showing up.

Server: Physical

OS: CentOS

Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:08:18 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:10:42 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

EDIT: I have used this https://pastebin.com/qZdQCjw1 docker-compose for init installation of all those apps in docker-compose file. After that I didn't change anything. This is a long shot, but could it be that I have installed docker-swarm and uninstalled it 1 min after installation that docker swarm change something, so I can't see ports for my containers?

Comment: Please can you add the commands you used to run them?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. I have tried to set specifically bridge network and assign it to all containers in docker-compose file. I have played with docker swarm for a minute and when I removed everything related to docker swarm, it still had overlay network, which is the reason why I missed ports. I had to manually set bridge and assign it to all services in docker-compose file and now it works like a charm.